# Excel VBA how to copy cell content from one book to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro which will copy a cell content from one workbook to another.
The problem is that in the original workbook there are links to another worksheet inside this workbook and after my macro does the job, the links are referring to the sheet of the source file.
For example in the source file I have `=CONCATENATE(A1,Sheet2!A1)` and after copying the cell content becomes `=CONCATENATE(A1,[Source.xlsm]Sheet2!A1)`
Ho to avoid appearing this `[Source.xlsm]` ?

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim wbk As Workbook

    Range("A1:B1").Copy

    Set wbk = Application.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/subdir/destination.xlsx")
    With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) to strip **[Source.xlsm]** from the formulas.

```
With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .Cells.Replace What:="[Source.xlsm]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

btw, You were missing the `.` in `.Range("A1").PasteSpecial...`

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, It is a good trick. I was focusing my thoughts on copying already without the links to the source. BTW do you think is this possible ? This would be more universal way.